# Exporting entire CONST js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a separate JS file containing all my constants:

```
export const LABEL_1 = "Hello there"
export const LABEL_2 = 'Hi Madame'
export const LABEL_3 = 'Hello Sir'
```

I used to import all of them as:

```
import * as CONS from 'path/to/fileWithConstants'
```

Then access them as:

```
console.log(CONS.LABEL_1)
```

However, for simplicity, I prefer not to reference "CONS" anymore. So I did the import like this:

```
import { LABEL_1 } from 'path/to/fileWithConstants'
console.log(LABEL_1)
```

But I do not want to put each and every constant in the import line.

How can I import the entire file with all these constants (there are hundreds of them) without having to reference `CONS`??

Thanks!

Comment: At the moment there is no support for importing without using an alias. (As far as I know) Not really a solution to your problem, but using a smart enough IDE would help you as it could manage the imports itself.

Answer (score 1):

How about exporting them with a spread?

```js
import * as CONS from 'path/to/fileWithConstants'

export {
    ...CONS,
}
```